# prevent any app from stealing focus in windows

Tags: windows-10, focus

Is there a way to prevent any app from stealing focus in windows 10?
I would like to open documents and run software in the background without them popping up whenever they're done.

Answer (score 2):

From : [windows-10-stop-any-application-from-stealing-focus-ever-is-it-possible](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c22363e5-802c-4f43-b4e3-8a7259865648/windows-10-stop-any-application-from-stealing-focus-ever-is-it-possible?forum=win10itprogeneral#123b4fea-0a57-491d-bdfa-a5ee0771f2de)

> 1. Start the Registry Editor (Start button + R, then type regedit)
> 2. Search for HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control
>    Panel\Desktop\ForegroundLockTimeout
> 3. Change the value from 0 to 30d40
> 4. Save and restart the computer

Comment: thanks for your input, the value was already 30d40 by default, still having the issue.

Comment: @Jimmy Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: This has been a problem for so long that I think the actual answer is: "Get a job at Microsoft and fix it yourself."